# Creating dag level global variable with in airflow v2.2.4

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I am trying to create dag level variable inside dag with jinja templating macros but it is not working. It is working if I define it under python operator but I need to use same variable also in following operators:

- BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator
- GCSToBigQueryOperator
- GCSDeleteObjectsOperator

Is there way to define that that? Variable should point 2 days before of dag_run.

```
import os
import pendulum
import requests

from datetime import timedelta
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.macros import ds_add
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_bigquery import GCSToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.gcs import GCSDeleteObjectsOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator

REPORT_DATE = ds_add("{{ ds }}",-3). ### problematic var
## other vars

with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_name',
    schedule_interval='30 6 * * *',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 1, 1, tz="Europe/Amsterdam"),
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=15),
    tags=['appsflyer', 'external_data','bigquery'],
    params={"retries": 1, "report_datex" : "ds_add('{{ ds }}',-5)"},
) as dag:

    purge_target_table = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
        task_id='purge_target_table',
        sql=f"DELETE FROM {DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} where date='{REPORT_DATE}'",
        use_legacy_sql=False
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `params` should be set in the operator not in the DAG.
Second, `params` is not templated field so you can not pass macros with it. Macros should be used directly with the templated field:

```
sql=f"DELETE FROM {DATASET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAME} where date='ds_add("{{ ds }}",-3)'"
```